# How to change date input type to DD/MM/YYYY in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, date

I am using property as input type ="datetime". But this property view the output MM/DD/YYYY. so how do I change the output format of the Date to DD/MM/YYYY?

[pick the date format mm/dd/yyyy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/38vPm.jpg)

```
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>{{"StartDate" | localize}}*</label>
                            <input required class="form-control m-input" type="datetime" bsDatepicker 
                            datePickerMomentModifier [(date)]="ticketWorkDetail.workDetailStartDate" 
                            id="TicketWorkDetail_WorkDetailStartDate" 
                            name="TicketWorkDetail_WorkDetailStartDate">
                        </div>
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: are you using ngx-bootstrap?

Comment: from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date#Browser_compatibility: "The displayed date format will differ from the actual value — the displayed date is formatted based **on the locale of the user's browser**, but the parsed value is always formatted yyyy-mm-dd."

Comment: you can use ng-bootstrap, material-date-picker, ngx-bootstrap ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ngx-bootstrap... I think you are from the bsDatepicker directive on your input. You can use the `bsConfig` directive to format the date input. https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/datepicker#format

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>{{"StartDate" | localize}}*</label>
    <input required class="form-control m-input" type="text" bsDatepicker 
    datePickerMomentModifier [(date)]="ticketWorkDetail.workDetailStartDate"
    [bsConfig]="{ dateInputFormat: 'DD/MM/YYYY' }" 
    id="TicketWorkDetail_WorkDetailStartDate" 
    name="TicketWorkDetail_WorkDetailStartDate">
</div>
```

You can set the input type attribute to text and the `bsDatepicker` directive will do it's work.